# Condor Vanilla universe is running on submit machine

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, condor

I am new to condor. I am doing my master project on condor by using no. of raspberry pi. Currently i have connected two pi together in a condor pool; I am referring "http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/tutorials/fermi-2005/simple_dag.html" website to run a job.
But the problem is job is running on submit machine itself.

Can anybody please help me regarding this. It will be really a great help.

**Submit file is**

```
Universe   = vanilla
Executable = simple
should_transfer_files = yes
when_to_transfer_output = on_exit
MultiCPUJob = True
transfer_input_files = simple.dag
Arguments  = 4 10
Log        = simple.log
Output     = simple.out
Error      = simple.error
Queue
```

**Log file**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/job $ cat simple.log

000 (012.000.000) 02/25 06:00:21 Job submitted from host: <10.0.101.122:46766>
    DAG Node: simple

...
001 (012.000.000) 02/25 06:00:31 Job executing on host: <10.0.101.122:36154>
...

006 (012.000.000) 02/25 06:00:35 Image size of job updated: 7

        0  -  MemoryUsage of job (MB)

        0  -  ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...

005 (012.000.000) 02/25 06:00:36 Job terminated.

        (1) Normal termination (return value 0)

                Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Remote Usage

                Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Local Usage

                Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Remote Usage

                Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Local Usage

        56  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job

        6230  -  Run Bytes Received By Job

        56  -  Total Bytes Sent By Job

        6230  -  Total Bytes Received By Job

        Partitionable Resources :    Usage  Request Allocated

           Cpus                 :                 1         1

           Disk (KB)            :       14       10     76532

           Memory (MB)          :        0        1       434

...

pi@raspberrypi:~/job $
```

Answer (score 0):

If the job is running on the submit machine, it must be running a STARTD as well as SCHEDD, NEG, etc... if you don't need this, then you can switch it off in your /etc/condor/condor_config (or condor_config.local, depending on setup).

If you want the submit node to be able to run some jobs, but just not these ones, then you can specify

requirements = TARGET.Machine==foo@bar.com

to force it to run on a particular machine, or use anything specific about your requirements which filter out that submit node, using the ClassAds for the start nodes (use condor_status -l to view these). You can specify these ClassAds yourself in the config files and then use them to set the requirements for your jobs. e.g.
Start Node: condor_config.local
POOL=start_pool

SubmitNode: submit.dag
requirements=POOL=="start_pool"
to give yourself better customization.